# Image SSD calculation error value

Tags: python, numpy

Following is the code, this function is to get the SSD (sum of standard differences) matrix of the input. Input `video_volume` is a list of images (4D numpy arrays, format: `(num_frames, rows, cols, 3)`).

However, when I pass in the following matrix, it doesn't work. It seems the square of 255 is overflowing or something happens to 255?

### Test input:

```
np.array([[[[2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2]],
           [[2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2]]],
          [[[1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]],
           [[1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]]],
          [[[0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]],
           [[255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255]]]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

### Expected output:

```
[[  0.00000000e+00   2.40000000e+01   7.68156000e+05]
 [  2.40000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   7.74204000e+05]
 [  7.68156000e+05   7.74204000e+05   0.00000000e+00]]
```

### Actual output:

```
[[   0.   24.  156.]
 [  24.    0.   60.]
 [ 156.   60.    0.]]
```

### SSD function:

```
output = np.zeros((len(video_volume), len(video_volume)), dtype=np.float)
ssd = 0
for i in range(len(video_volume)):
    cur_frame = video_volume[i]
    #print 'i:{}'.format(i)
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        comparison_frame = video_volume[j]
        ssd = float(np.sum((cur_frame[:,:,0:3] - comparison_frame[:,:,0:3])**2))
        output[i][j] = ssd            
        if i != j:
            output[j][i] = ssd

return output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dtype of your input array is `np.uint8`. An 8-bit unsigned integer can store 2<sup>8</sup>  different values, i.e. from 0 to 255. You will therefore get overflow wherever the value of the sum of squared differences:

```
np.sum((cur_frame[:,:,0:3] - comparison_frame[:,:,0:3])**2)
```

is greater than 255. Since it is an unsigned format, uint8 also can't represent negative values, so you will also run into underflow if any value in

```
cur_frame[:,:,0:3] - comparison_frame[:,:,0:3]
```

is negative.

An easy workaround is to cast your input to a signed integer format with a higher bit depth:

```
video_volume = video_volume.astype(np.int64)
```